# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac debug question: views or code not updated

Tags: macos, debugging, visual-studio-mac

Today I started working with Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.
Works fine and fast but debugging is not working the way I expect.
So question is: am I doing something wrong or do I expect something which will never happen :) ?

- new project Net Core 3.1
- recent model Apple Macbook Pro, 8Gb
- during debug breakpoints are hit
- able to edit code during debug (even when not in pause mode?)
- pause and (re)start buttons are responding well.
- debugger automatically 'paused' on breakpoints, 'continue' by click play button
- while in debug mode: using clean solution does not have effect

Problem:
Changes in code behind (controllers,models) not available, same for a View (.cshtml files)
The only way to notice or view changes is to stop and start the debugger.
Which is not very efficient.

Question
Is this normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?
I thought that code changes should be available directly while in debug mode after click 'play/continue' button (which should trigger recompile of the code) .

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Unfortunately Visual Studio for Mac does not support reload changes made to cshtml files whilst the app is open, you would need to stop and restart the debugger. If you are not interested in debugging at the same time you could maybe use dotnet watch instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll try this. It looks like it starts a web application from a folder, just like what VS does when calling the debugger? I am curious if it works, and if so, why it works :)

Comment: I have tried to make it work with dotnet watch but did not succeed. Honestly I think I do not understand enough of this to understand how this should work. On the other hand I just wonder why VS on Mac does not offer the same debug options as on Windows and why I need an extra tool just to watch realtime changes which is the main reason why you use an app like VS?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac unfortunately does not have all the same features as Visual Studio on Windows since whilst there is sharing of code not all of it is available on the Mac nor all of it has been integrated. Visual Studio for Mac does not have the edit and continue debugging feature, and it also does not refresh open web sites when they have been edited. Feature requests can be filed on developer community - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/visual-studio-for-mac.html?type=idea